# Print plot(lm(y~x) in R using png() and dev.off()

Tags: linux, r, plot, png

I'd like to print-to-file the regression diagnostic charts that R produces when you plot() the fit of a linear model.  There are four, and they interrupt execution with

```
Hit <Return> to see next plot:
Hit <Return> to see next plot: 
Hit <Return> to see next plot: 
Hit <Return> to see next plot:
```

So, the following code, which normally does work, did not:

```
png('Filename.png', width=mywidth, height=myheight, units='in', res=300)
plot(lm(y~x)
dev.off()
```

in that I still had to hit enter each time, and it isn't clear this would have properly subplotted, or named each plot as a different file.

How can I capture these diagnostic images directly printed to disk?  If it matters, I'm on a linux machine.

Comment: Give an example of the summary that causes the "Hit Return to see next plot".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A couple of options are, using the following dummy data

```
set.seed(42)
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- 3.4 + (0.5 * x) + rnorm(100)
```

Use the `ask` argument and set it to `FALSE`:

```
png('Filename%03d.png', width=6, height=6, units='in', res=300)
plot(lm(y~x), ask = FALSE)
dev.off()
```

Note that we have to use `%03d` to add a number to "Filename" so we have `"Filename001.png"` etc. for the four images. See `?plot.lm` for the details of `ask` and `?png` for the notation in the filename.

Alternatively, set up the plotting device with 4 panels and plot the model:

```
png("Filename_all.png", width=6, height=6, units='in', res=300)
layout(matrix(1:4, ncol = 2))
plot(lm(y~x))
layout(1)
dev.off()
```